# Receiving 32-bit registers from 64-bit nasm code

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64, cpu-registers

I am learning 64-bit nasm, I assemble the .nasm file, which ONLY contains 64-bit registers, by doing the following

```
nasm -f elf64 HelloWorld.nasm -o HelloWorld.o
```

and link it doing the following

```
ld HelloWorld.o -o HelloWorld
```

the program runs correctly and even says it is a 64-bit ELF when I run the `file` command, but when I use `objdump` or `gdb` to disassemble the executable, the registers I put as 64-bit registers in the code show up as 32-bit registers when disassembled. (example: `rax` in source showing up as `eax` when disassembled)

Why is this?

This does not happen on just one computer, and it is a new problem, it hasn't been doing this before.

**HelloWorld.nasm:**

```
global _start

section .text

_start:
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, hello_world
        mov rdx, length
        syscall

        mov rax, 60
        mov rdi, 11
        syscall

section .data

        hello_world: db 'Hello World',0xa
        length: equ $-hello_world
```

**Disassembled HelloWorld:**

```
...
00000000004000b0 <_start>:
  4000b0:       b8 01 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x1
  4000b5:       bf 01 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x1
  4000ba:       48 be d8 00 60 00 00    movabs rsi,0x6000d8
  4000c1:       00 00 00
  4000c4:       ba 0c 00 00 00          mov    edx,0xc
  4000c9:       0f 05                   syscall
  4000cb:       b8 3c 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x3c
  4000d0:       bf 0b 00 00 00          mov    edi,0xb
  4000d5:       0f 05                   syscall
...
```

Comment: Its not **all** registers, only those where you mov values which fit into 32 bits, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-most-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register

Comment: Basically a duplicate of the more recent [Why NASM on Linux changes registers in x86\_64 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48596247)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why does

```
...
mov rax, 1
mov rdi, 1
mov rsi, hello_world
...
```

gets disassembled as

```
...
4000b0:       b8 01 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x1
4000b5:       bf 01 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x1
4000ba:       48 be d8 00 60 00 00    movabs rsi,0x6000d8
4000c1:       00 00 00
...
```

Because the literal `0x1` fits into 32 bits, and [the upper 32 bits of a 64 bit register are set to `0` when loading the lower 32 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-most-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register) through the corresponding `E`-register. Hence the assembler can optimize the `mov` to a 32 bit operation.

Note that the address loaded into `rsi` might not fit into 32 bits, hence `rsi` remains as such.

If you add the following instructions, you can see the effect very clearly:

```
mov rbx, 0x0ffffffff      ; still fits into 32 bit
mov rbx, 0x100000000      ; does not fit into 32 bits anymore
```

gets disassembled as

```
 a: bb ff ff ff ff          mov    $0xffffffff,%ebx
 f: 48 bb 00 00 00 00 01    movabs $0x100000000,%rbx
16: 00 00 00
```

You can disable nasm optimization with `-O0`,  in which case the instructions keep their long format:

```
nasm -O0 -f elf64 HelloWorld.asm
```

Result:

```
14: 48 bb ff ff ff ff 00    movabs $0xffffffff,%rbx
1b: 00 00 00 
1e: 48 bb 00 00 00 00 01    movabs $0x100000000,%rbx
25: 00 00 00
```

Comment: You can use `objdump -drwC -Mintel` to get disassembly that's closer to NASM syntax, like the OP did.  See also [Why NASM on Linux changes registers in x86\_64 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48596247) - the other option (instead of `nasm -O0`) is `mov rax, strict dword 60` to use a sign-extended 32-bit immediate with 64-bit operand-size.  Or `mov rax, strict qword 1` to force a 64-bit immediate.  `nasm -O0` make very inefficient asm all over the place so you wouldn't want to actually use it, but might sometimes want a longer encoding for alignment reasons.