# Why NASM on Linux changes registers in x86_64 assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64, micro-optimization, shellcode

I am new to x86_64 assembly programming. I was writing simple "Hello World" program in x86_64 assembly. Below is my code, which runs perfectly fine.

```
global _start

section .data

    msg: db "Hello to the world of SLAE64", 0x0a
    mlen equ $-msg

section .text
    _start:
            mov rax, 1
            mov rdi, 1
            mov rsi, msg
            mov rdx, mlen
            syscall

            mov rax, 60
            mov rdi, 4
            syscall
```

Now when I disassemble in gdb, it gives below output:

```
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function _start:
=> 0x00000000004000b0 <+0>:     mov    eax,0x1
   0x00000000004000b5 <+5>:     mov    edi,0x1
   0x00000000004000ba <+10>:    movabs rsi,0x6000d8
   0x00000000004000c4 <+20>:    mov    edx,0x1d
   0x00000000004000c9 <+25>:    syscall
   0x00000000004000cb <+27>:    mov    eax,0x3c
   0x00000000004000d0 <+32>:    mov    edi,0x4
   0x00000000004000d5 <+37>:    syscall
End of assembler dump.
```

My question is why NASM behaves in such way? I know it changes instructions based on opcode, but I am not sure about same behaviour with registers.

Also does this behaviour affects functionality of executable?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit) installed in VMware on i5 processor.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's size optimization. `mov rax,1` has exactly the same effect as `mov eax,1` (because on x86-64 writing to 32 bit register variant like `eax` will automatically clear upper 32 bits of the 64 bit `rax`, that's how AMD designed the x86-64). And the `eax` variant is 1B shorter opcode for the tiny immediate (the `rax` has exactly same opcode with REX prefix byte ahead). - But I didn't think it is doing it even in this case, surprised me a bit (I was aware only of `mov eax,1` picking the `imm8` opcode variant automatically, unless you write `mov eax, dword 1` to force it to use `imm32` one).

Comment: Just a comment (not answer), because I'm too lazy to check for dupes.

Comment: @Ped7g: It's not strictly a duplicate AFAIK; other questions have come at the same issue from different directions, but I don't remember seeing one asking why NASM does it.  (I didn't search either, though, because it's a good enough question that I wasn't looking for a way to close it)

Comment: @Ped7g: "I was aware only of `mov eax,1` picking the `imm8` opcode variant automatically" - Actually there is no 8-bit extending immediate form of `mov`, you are mistaken.

Comment: An earlier duplicate where the answer shows some examples disassembly to illustrate the differences: [Receiving 32-bit registers from 64-bit nasm code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26504930)

Answer (score 8):

In 64-bit mode `mov eax, 1` will clear the upper part of the `rax` register (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register) for an explanation) thus `mov eax, 1` is semantically equivalent to `mov rax, 1`.

The former however spare a *REX.W* (`48h` numerically) prefix (a byte necessary to specify the registers introduced with x86-64), the opcode is the same for both instructions (`0b8h` followed by a DWORD or a QWORD).
So the assembler goes ahead and picks up the shortest form.

This is a typical behavior of NASM, see [Section 3.3](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.3) of the NASM's manual where the example of `[eax*2]` is assembled as `[eax+eax]` to spare the `disp32` field after the *SIB* byte<sup>1</sup> (`[eax*2]` is only encodable as `[eax*2+disp32]` where the assembler set `disp32` to 0).

I was unable to force NASM to emit a real `mov rax, 1` instruction (i.e. `48 B8 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`) even by prefixing the instruction with `o64`.
If a real `mov rax, 1` is needed (this is not your case), one must resort to assembling it manually with `db` and similar.

**EDIT**: [Peter Cordes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48597025/5801661) shows that there is, in fact, a way to tell NASM *not* to optimize an instruction with the [`strict`](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.7) modifier.
`mov rax, STRICT 1` produces the 10-byte version of the instruction (`mov r64, imm64`) while `mov rax, STRICT DWORD 1` produces a 7-byte version (`mov r64, imm32` where `imm32` is *sign-extended* before use).

---

Side note: It's better to use the [RIP-relative addressing](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/03/understanding-the-x64-code-models), this avoids 64-bit immediate constants (thus reducing code size) and is [mandatory in MacOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachOTopics/1-Articles/x86_64_code.html) (in case you cared).
Change the `mov esi, msg` to `lea esi, [REL msg]` (RIP-relative is an *addressing mode* so it needs an "addressing", the square bracket, to avoid reading from that address we use `lea` that only computes the effective address but does no access).
You can use the directive `DEFAULT REL` to avoid typing `REL` in each memory access.

I was under the impression that the [Mach-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O) file format required PIC code but [this may not be the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48596247/why-nasm-on-linux-changes-registers-in-x86-64-assembly/48596926?noredirect=1#comment84190847_48596926).

---

<sup>1</sup> The *Scale Index Base* byte, used to encode the new addressing mode introduced back then with the 32-bit mode.

Comment: `mov rax, strict dword 1`, see my answer.

Comment: I've seen posts saying that `mov rsi, msg` worked on OS X for a similar hello-world executable.  OS X maps executables above 4GiB, so you need 64-bit constants for addresses, but it apparently *doesn't* require PIC executables, or it supports text relocations to fix-up the 64-bit absolute addresses after ASLR.

Comment: @PeterCordes, Thank you for the `strict` modifier, I was missing that. Regarding MacOS, I was under the impression that Mach-o required PIC (and didn't support 64-bit fixups) but I never experimented with a Mac so I'm quoting your comment verbatim :)

Comment: That's what I used to think, so maybe you got that impression from something I wrote.  I probably conflated needing 64-bit address support with needing PIC, because why would you give up the efficiency of 32-bit absolute addresses except to require PIC / ASLR?  But yeah, Linux does 64-bit fixups for PIC code (which also surprised me), so perhaps OS X does the same.  IDK what the point of supporting that is.  It lets you make absolute jump tables, I guess, so maybe as a side-effect of supporting it for data, it also works on immediates.

Answer (score 6):

**TL:DR**: You can override this with

- `mov eax, 1` (explicitly use the optimal operand-size)
  `b8 01 00 00 00`
- `mov rax, strict dword 1` (sign-extended 32-bit immediate)
  `48 c7 c0 01 00 00 00`
- `mov rax, strict qword 1` (64-bit immediate like `movabs` in AT&T syntax)
  `48 b8 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`
  (Also `mov rax, strict 1` is equivalent to this, and is what you get if you disable NASM optimization.)

---

**This is a perfectly safe and useful optimization**, similar to using an 8-bit immediate instead of a 32-bit immediate when you write `add eax, 1`.

NASM only optimizes when the shorter form of the instruction has an identical architectural effect, because [`mov eax,1` implicitly zeros the upper 32 bits of RAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register).  Note that `add rax, 0` is different from `add eax, 0` so NASM can't optimize that: Only instructions like `mov r32,...` / `mov r64,...` or `xor eax,eax` that don't depend on the old value of the 32 vs. 64-bit register can be optimized this way.  (NASM doesn't optimize `xor rax,rax` or other zeroing idioms, though; [you should always use 32-bit operand-size manually for xor-zeroing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and).)

---

**You can disable it with `nasm -O1` (the default is `-Ox` multipass)**, but note that you'll get 10-byte `mov rax, strict qword 1` in that case: clearly NASM isn't intended to really be used with less than normal optimization.  There isn't a setting where it will use the shortest encoding that wouldn't change the disassembly (e.g. 7-byte `mov rax, sign_extended_imm32` = `mov rax, strict dword 1`).

The difference between `-O0` and `-O1` is in imm8 vs. imm32, e.g. `add rax, 1` is
`48 83 C0 01` (`add r/m64, sign_extended_imm8`) with `-O1`, vs.
`48 05 01000000` (`add rax, sign_extended_imm32`) with `nasm -O0`.
Amusingly it still optimized by picking the special-case opcode that implies an RAX destination instead of taking a ModRM byte.  Unfortunately `-O1` doesn't optimize immediate sizes for `mov` (where sign_extended_imm8 isn't possible.)

If you ever need a specific encoding somewhere, ask for it with `strict` instead of disabling optimization.

---

##### Other assemblers

Note that YASM doesn't do this operand-size optimization, so it's a good idea to make the optimization yourself in the asm source, if you care about code-size (even indirectly for performance reasons) in code that could be assembled with other NASM-compatible assemblers.

For instructions where 32 and 64-bit operand size wouldn't be equivalent if you had very large (or negative) numbers, you need to use 32-bit operand-size explicitly even if you're assembling with NASM instead of YASM, if you want the size / performance advantage.
**[The advantages of using 32bit registers/instructions in x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303333/the-advantages-of-using-32bit-registers-instructions-in-x86-64)**

**GAS will do this optimization with as `-Os`**, e.g. `gcc -Wa,-Os  -c foo.S`, but that's unfortunately not the default.  (`gcc -O` options don't influence options passed to `as`, even when an explicit input is a `.s` or `.S`.  Using `gcc -O3 -Wa,-Os  foo.c` is a good idea if you have any inline asm you aren't sure is manually optimized, assuming it wasn't hand-optimized to use longer instructions for alignment reasons.)

---

#### 64-bit constants that fit in 32-bit zero or sign-extended

**For 32-bit constants that don't have their high bit set, zero or sign extending them to 64 bits gives an identical result**.  Thus it's a pure optimization to assemble `mov rax, 1` to a 5-byte `mov r32, imm32` (with implicit zero extension to 64 bits) instead of a 7-byte `mov r/m64, sign_extended_imm32`.

(See [Difference between movq and movabsq in x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315803/difference-between-movq-and-movabsq-in-x86-64) for more details about the forms of `mov` x86-64 allows; AT&T syntax has a special name for the 10-byte immediate form but NASM doesn't.)

#### Performance

On all current x86 CPUs, the only performance difference between that and the 7-byte encoding is code-size, so only indirect effects like alignment and L1I$ pressure are a factor.  Internally it's just a mov-immediate, so this optimization doesn't change the microarchitectural effect of your code either (except of course for code-size / alignment / how it packs in the uop cache).

The 10-byte `mov r64, imm64` encoding is even worse for code size.  If the constant actually has any of its high bits set, then it has extra inefficiency in the uop cache on Intel Sandybridge-family CPUs (using 2 entries in the uop cache, and maybe an extra cycle to read from the uop cache).  But if the constant is in the -2^31 .. +2^31 range (signed 32-bit), it's stored internally just as efficiently, using only a single uop-cache entry, even if it was encoded in the x86 machine code using a 64-bit immediate.  (See [Agner Fog's microarch doc](http://agner.org/optimize/), *Table 9.1. Size of different instructions in μop cache in the Sandybridge section*)

From [How many ways to set a register to zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829937/how-many-ways-to-set-a-register-to-zero), **you can force any of the three encodings:**

```
mov    eax, 1                ; 5 bytes to encode (B8 imm32)
mov    rax, strict dword 1   ; 7 bytes: REX mov r/m64, sign-extended-imm32.    NASM optimizes mov rax,1 to the 5B version, but dword or strict dword stops it for some reason
mov    rax, strict qword 1   ; 10 bytes to encode (REX B8 imm64).  movabs mnemonic for AT&T.  Normally assemblers choose smaller encodings if the operand fits, but strict qword forces the imm64.
```

---

Note that NASM used the 10-byte encoding (which AT&T syntax calls `movabs`, and so does `objdump` in Intel-syntax mode) for an address which is a link-time constant but unknown at assemble time.

YASM chooses `mov r64, imm32`, i.e. it assumes a code-model where label addresses are 32 bits, unless you use `mov rsi, strict qword msg`

YASM's behaviour is normally good (although using `mov r32, imm32` for static absolute addresses like C compilers do would be even better).  The default non-PIC code-model puts all static code/data in the low 2GiB of virtual address space, so zero- or sign-extended 32-bit constants can hold addresses.

If you want 64-bit label addresses you should normally use `lea r64, [rel address]` to do a RIP-relative LEA.  (On Linux at least, position-dependent code can go in the low 32, so unless you're using the large / huge code models, any time you need to care about 64-bit label addresses, you're also making PIC code where you should use RIP-relative LEA to avoid needing text relocations of absolute address constants).

i.e. **gcc and other compilers would have used `mov esi, msg`, or `lea rsi, [rel msg]`, never `mov rsi, msg`**.
See [How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212012/how-to-load-address-of-function-or-label-into-register)

Comment: Fun fact: GAS will do this optimization with `as -Os`, e.g. `gcc -Wa,-Os`, but that's unfortunately not the default.