# Why does it take less bytes to use `xor` than to use `mov`?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, machine-code, code-size

For setting x to zero (x = 0), my csapp book indicates two ways.

First:

```
xorq %rcx, %rcx
```

Second:

```
movq $0, %rcx
```

It also tells that the first one takes only 3 bytes, but the second one takes 7 bytes.

How do the two ways work? Why does the first one take fewer bytes than the second one?

Comment: Different instructions in x86 are different sizes. xor takes fewer bytes to encode.

Comment: Check the instruction set reference for the encodings of these instructions.  That said, `xor %eax, %eax` is even shorter at only two bytes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Because `mov` needs more space to encode its 32-bit immediate source operand.**
`xor` only needs the ModRM byte to encode its operands.

Neither one needs a REX prefix so **you should be comparing 2-byte `xor %ecx,%ecx` against 5-byte `mov $0, %ecx`**.  [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-most-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register)
GAS doesn't do this optimization for you, and `movq` gives you the `mov $sign_extended_imm32, %r/m64` encoding instead of the special case 5-byte `mov $imm32, %r32` encoding that omits the ModRM byte.
(Unless you use `as -O2` in which case it will [optimize the operand-size  like NASM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48596247/why-nasm-on-linux-changes-registers-in-x86-64-assembly/48597025#48597025).  Note that `gcc -O2 -c foo.s` does *not* pass on optimization options to `as`.)

(As noted in [CS:APP example uses idivq with two operands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57998998/csapp-example-uses-idivq-with-two-operands), CS:APP seems to be full of asm mistakes.  This one isn't an invalid-syntax mistake, just a missed optimization.)

---

There is unfortunately no encoding of `mov` with a sign-extended 8-bit immediate, otherwise we could have 3-byte `mov reg, imm8`.  (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov).  (I'm surprised no iteration of x86-64 has repurposed one of opcode bytes it freed up for a nice `mov` encoding like that, maybe lumped in with BMI1 or something.)

For more details on x86 instruction encoding, read Intel's vol.2 manual and look at disassembly, and https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding is a nice overview that's less verbose than Intel's manual.

See also [What is the best way to set a register to zero in x86 assembly: xor, mov or and?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and) for more details about why xor-zeroing is optimal: on some CPUs, notably P6-family and Sandybridge-family, it has microarchitectural advantages over `mov` besides simply code-size.

Answer (score 4):

> Why does the first one take fewer bytes than second?

While Peter Cordes' answer is already about the technical details, I'd like to focus on the mathematical background:

x86s CPU obviously does not distinguish between large numbers (like 12345789) and the value zero: For storing such a value 4 bytes are required.

However, the value zero is a very special value:

It can be written as (a-a) or as (a XOR a) while "a" can be any integer value!

This means that you can perform a trick:

You perform the operation `subq %rcx, %rcx` to calculate the value `(rcx - rcx)`. It does not care which value `rcx` has: If you subtract that value from itself, the result will be zero (because (a-a)=0).

This means that `rcx` will be 0 after that operation.

The operation `xorq %rcx, %rcx` has the same effect, because (a XOR a) is also always 0.

Comment: 1-byte immediate are supported for most instructions *other* than `mov`.  e.g. `add $4, %ecx` is 3 bytes (opcode + modrm + sign_extended_imm8) while `add $4096, %ecx` is 6 bytes (opcode + modrm + imm32).  So your 2nd paragraph about x86 not treating small values specially should maybe limit itself to `mov`.  But yes, +1 for explaining `a^a = a-a = 0`.  Forgot to put anything about that in my answer.